# Drawing in a NSWindow

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, objective-c++, nsopengl

I'm working on a cocoa wrapper for a graphics framework.

To finally draw the stuff, I'm doing this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect
{
 CGContextRef ctx = (CGContextRef)[[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort];
 CGContextDrawImage(ctx, NSRectToCGRect(rect), image);
}
```

inside a subclass of `NSView`.

Now I've looked at other frameworks like Gosu, Irrlicht, etc. and I saw they were always doing complicated `NSOpenGL` stuff like:

```
// Settings, depending on fullscreen or not
NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute windowedAttrs[] =
{
 NSOpenGLPFADoubleBuffer,
 NSOpenGLPFAScreenMask,
 (NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute)CGDisplayIDToOpenGLDisplayMask(CGMainDisplayID()),
 NSOpenGLPFADepthSize,
 (NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute)16,
 (NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute)0
};
NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute fullscreenAttrs[] =
{
 NSOpenGLPFADoubleBuffer,
 NSOpenGLPFAScreenMask,
 (NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute)CGDisplayIDToOpenGLDisplayMask(CGMainDisplayID()),
 NSOpenGLPFAFullScreen,
 NSOpenGLPFADepthSize,
 (NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute)16,
 (NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute)0
};
NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute* attrs = fullscreen ? fullscreenAttrs : windowedAttrs;

// Create pixel format and OpenGL context
ObjRef<NSOpenGLPixelFormat> fmt(
  [[NSOpenGLPixelFormat alloc] initWithAttributes:attrs]);
::context = [[NSOpenGLContext alloc] initWithFormat: fmt.obj() shareContext:nil];
```

Why are they doing all that? Is my "simple" way okay?

Comment: If it works, it's okay, _wenn ich in meinem Plutarch lese von großen Menschen_!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with ryyst. You are using CGContext which is essentially the Quartz 2D API. OpenGL is another option for graphics especially good for complex 3D rendering.